# Substitute same number of repeated characters with others using Regex

Tags: regex, string, perl

I want to replace the repeating characters with other character for the same amount of repeated character and if it is repeating at the start of the string. Minimum repeating number should be more than 2.

For ex: $string = 'bbbbabcdeeeeee' 
Here bbbb should be replaced with yyyy

But if $string = 'bbcccccccddddddeeeffdfg' should not replace anything as first repeating character is not more than two times

`$string =~ s/^(b){3,}/y/`   would replace only more than 2 b to only one y

Is it possible to substitute using one line regular expression?
Note: It would be nice if someone would respond in Perl or Python.

Comment: In which language/tool you want this?

Comment: Its Perl Programming Language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use code like this:

```
$string='bbbbcccccccddddddeeeffdfg';
$string =~ s/^((\w)\2{2,})/'y' x length($1)/e;
print $string. "\n";
```

#### OUTPUT

```
yyyycccccccddddddeeeffdfg
```

- `/e` -> To execute code in replacement
- `'y' x length($1)` -> To repeat character `'y'` as many times as the length of matched group #1

Comment: To make it generic use; `$string =~ s/^((\w)\2{2,})/'y' x length($1)/e;`

Comment: length($1) would be length of total characters not just length of word.
i.e. bb.bb.bb.mgm s/^((bb\.){2,})/'y' x length($1)/e;
would replace like this yyyyyyyyymgm instead of yyymgm

Comment: `length($1)` will be length of first matched group.

Comment: With the generic solution `bb.bb.bb.mgm` will remain `bb.bb.bb.mgm` since `b` is repeated only twice.

Comment: If input is `bbb.bb.bb.mgm` then it will become `yyy.bb.bb.mgm`

Comment: I agree but I specifically mention \. in group too i.e. it will not just look for bb, it will look for bb. pattern so in that case it should be 3. Correct me if I am wrong.  You are very helpful and kind :) Thanks Anubhava \m/

Comment: It can be tweaked for dot character but can dot be first character also? Also note that in this case it wont be pure repetition.

Comment: what is the significance of using \2 there before {2,} and \w means workd [a-zA-z_], so we have to be careful while using it, right :)

Comment: `\2` is back reference to matched group #2 i.e. the very first character matched by `\w`. If you want to match just anything then `$string =~ s/^((.)\2{2,})/'y' x length($1)/e;` will work. `{2,}` is there since one match has already been made and `2 and more` need to be matched further.

Comment: Thanks missed that part in prel regex manual : http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
my $re = qr~^((.)\2{2,})~;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    s:$re:'y' x length($1):e;
    say;
}


__DATA__
bbbbabcdeeeeee
bbcccccccddddddeeeffdfg
xxxxxx
```

**output:**

```
yyyyabcdeeeeee
bbcccccccddddddeeeffdfg
yyyyyy
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in which language you wan't this, but i will make a php script sample and you can convert it to your language of choice:

```
php > echo preg_replace('/([^b])b{3}([^b])/','$1yyy$2','aaabbbccc');
aaayyyccc
php > echo preg_replace('/([^b])b{3}([^b])/','$1yyy$2','aaaabbbbcccc');
aaaabbbbcccc
```

**EDIT**

If you want to only match beginning chars use tick char:

```
php > echo preg_replace('/^b{3}([^b])/','yyy$2','aaaabbbbcccc');
aaaabbbbcccc
php > echo preg_replace('/^b{3}([^b])/','yyy$2','bbbbcccc');
bbbbcccc
php > echo preg_replace('/^b{3}([^b])/','yyy$2','bbbcccc');
yyyccc
php > echo preg_replace('/^b{3}([^b])/','yyy$2','bbcccc');
bbcccc
```

perl version :

```
#/usr/bin/perl
$string = 'bbbccc';
$string =~ s/^b{3}([^b])/yyy$1/;
print $string;
$string = 'bbcc';
$string =~ s/^b{3}([^b])/yyy$1/;
print $string;
$string = 'bbbbcccc';
$string =~ s/^b{3}([^b])/yyy$1/;
print $string;
```

Comment: It should check for repeating characters only at the start of the string and only starting string would get replaced.

You code is checking at the middle of the string!

Comment: Again, I didn't stated just 3 it could be three or more :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to replace just a specific character, then in bash (using sed) you can use the following:

```
# echo aabcddd | sed '/\(a\)\{3,\}/{s/a/y/g}'
aabcddd
# echo aaabcddd | sed '/\(a\)\{3,\}/{s/a/y/g}'
yyybcddd
```

Comment: It will incorrectly replace `aaabcaaddd` to `yyybcyyddd`